# Remote Controlled / Network Media Player

Tags: macos, ubuntu, remote, media-player

I am looking for a Media Player that can be remote controlled with a Desktop Software (or even Web based) over the network. I know that there are tons of streaming servers and clients but that's exactly what I don't want to do.

The scenario is:
I have small Ubuntu File/Media Server that is connected to the stereo and two notebooks (Mac OS and Ubuntu) that should control the Media Servers Media player. I didn't find any good solution for that yet and I don't really want to use a remote desktop connection (ideally the desktop program should e.g. support importing new media to the server over the network and the server player runs only on command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For music, you can use [MPD (Music Player Daemon)](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki), which was specifically designed with remote control in mind. It runs as a server process and is controlled by clients like Sonata.

For video, I think you could use VLC, which can be remote-controlled from browser.

(sorry, as a new user, I can only post one link)

Comment: Updated link: https://www.musicpd.org/

Answer (score 2):

**VideoLAN**

- http://www.videolan.org/
- [List of Interfaces](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php?cat=intf)

Comment: There are also iPhone and Android apps that can act as remotes for VLC.

Comment: If your stuck with linux on the media server than VLC is probably the best way to go.  If you could serve files some OS X there would be some better options I think.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Remuco might be a good bet [SourceforgeWikiPage](http://remuco.sourceforge.net/index.php/Remuco) . It's a remote control system for Linux mediaplayers and mobile devices equipped with bluetooth or wifi. Looks like it would work with Banshee, Amarok and a bunch of other choices. (I'd assume you could run the client from your laptop or if you have a useable phone use that.

[image]